# How can i vectorize a matrix/ the input so that scipy.optimize.minimize can work with it?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I ran into an issue while converting a unconstrainted problem for scipy.optimize.minimize. I want to run the method L-BFGS.

The baseproblem looked like this:

min|| A - XY||

s.t. X,Y

while A is a given Matrix and X $\in \R^{nxl}$ and Y $\in \R^{lxm}
Since scipy only accept Vector inputs, i tried to interpret XY as a bigger variable: Z=(X,Y) where i already put the columns of X and Y under each other.

First i tried to program the function that it will convert my input vector. For a base example it worked fine (maybe because the matrix was dense? idk)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
R=np.array(np.arange(12)).reshape(3, 4)
Z0 = np.array(np.random.random(14))
#X=3x2 = 6
#Y=2x4 = 8
def whatineed (Z):
    return np.linalg.norm(R - np.dot(Z[:6].reshape(3,2),Z[6:].reshape(2,4)))

A = minimize(fun=whatineed, x0=Z0, method='L-BFGS-B', options={'disp': 1})

#print A
```

Above is just a (seemingly?) working dummy code. It gave me the/a result:

```
x: array([ 1.55308851, -0.50000733,  1.89812395,  1.44382572,  2.24315938, 3.38765876,  0.62668062,  1.23575295,  1.8448253 ,  2.45389762, 1.94655245,  1.83844053,  1.73032859,  1.62221667])
```

If i run it with a big one it doesnt work at all.

```
RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

           * * *

Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =       377400     M =           10
 This problem is unconstrained.

At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds
```

without moving further. R is in real a more or less sparse Matrix. But i really dont know WHERE to begin with. Is it my functioncode? Is it the sparsity of R? Both? What is the work around?

Update: Solver works with VERY small dimension. If i go a bit bigger this error occurs:

```
ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH                              

 Line search cannot locate an adequate point after 20 function
  and gradient evaluations.  Previous x, f and g restored.
 Possible causes: 1 error in function or gradient evaluation;
                  2 rounding error dominate computation.

 Cauchy                time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Subspace minimization time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Line search           time 0.000E+00 seconds.

 Total User time 0.000E+00 seconds.
```

As u can see at the User time, the problem is quite small and stops working.
Running it handwritten (L-BFGS) results in doing no steps/descents at all.

Comment: The first problem (no progress) looks like slow progress / memory problems due to *not* exploiting sparsity in your black-box objective. The second one is due to numerical problems and there is an easy recipe: provide symbolic (or let's say: do not use numerical-differentiation) gradients.**edit** can it be, that the dimensions also do not work out? your numbers look like that, but usually i would expect scipy to break earlier.

Comment: I also would start first with the more fitting algorithms of scipy, e.g. optimize.least_squares.

Comment: XY is just an arbitrary n x m matrix with rank <= l so the optimal solution is the SVD of A truncated to rank l.

Comment: @sascha  maybe but since i use an aranged np.array as my A this one is at least full of entries. The sparsity issue will come in later i guess but im not that far yet. i also asked another (very similar) question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155873/l-bfgs-solver-stops-working-when-i-increase-input-array-line-search-cannot-loc) were i included the mentioned gradient function. Similar issue just more detailed. I hope you check it out. My issues isnt the solver itself. i coded L-BFGS for myself and it didnt run either (it runs as good as this solver). It just stops working

Comment: @tch ok, im in. i know what truncated SVD is, but could you go a bit more specific about how to implement it here? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are trying to solve

```
min_{B is rank <= k} ‖ A - B ‖_2
```

the [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) is well known to be rank *k* truncated SVD of *A*.

Instead, we are trying to solve

```
min_{X,Y} ‖ A - XY ‖_2
```

where *X* has shape *n × k* and *Y* has shape *k × n* (I'm using *k* because it is easier to read than *l*)

**Claim:** these are equivalent problems. To see this we need to show that:

1. XY is rank <= *k* (with the above shapes).
2. any rank *k* matrix can be written as a product *XY* (with the above shapes).

**Proof:**

1. The first follows from the fact that *Y* is rank <= *k* and that the nulls pace of *XY* contains in the null space of *Y*
2. The second follows from writing the SVD of a rank <= *k* matrix *B = U D V** and observing that (UD) has shape *n × k* and *V* has shape *k × n* where we have dropped all but the first *k* singular values from the decomposition since they are guaranteed to be zero.

**Implementation**
To solve the problem OP stated we need only compute the SVD of *A* and truncate it to rank *k*.
You can use `np.linalg.svd` or `sp.sparse.linalg.svds` depending on if your matrix is sparse. For the numpy version the rank `k` svd can be computed as:

```
m,n = 10,20
A = np.random.randn(m,n)

k = 6
u,s,vt = np.linalg.svd(A)

X = u[:,:k]*s[:k]
Y = vt[:k]

print(X.shape, Y.shape)
print(np.linalg.norm(A-X@Y,2))
```

The syntax of `sp.sparse.linalg.svds` is almost the same except you are able to specify the rank you want ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks :). Is there a way to implement above in my obj_func?
I have to use L-BFGS and above example works, but does not really converge (i don't see a way how to implement it in some kind of iterating process (besides the process that is done by np.linalg.svd)

Comment: If you can write the Hessian explicitly then you could add that to your optimize call. The wikipedia page on [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) might be useful for that.